# Return a list of objects when using JAX-RS

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, jax-rs

How can I return a list of Question objects in XML or JSON?

```
@Path("all")
@GET
public List<Question> getAllQuestions() {
    return questionDAO.getAllQuestions();
}
```

I get this exception:

> SEVERE: Mapped exception to response: 500 (Internal Server Error)
>   javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException:
>   com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java
>   class java.util.Vector, and Java type
>   java.util.List, and MIME media
>   type application/octet-stream was not found

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
@Path("all")
@GET
public ArrayList<Question> getAllQuestions() {
    return (ArrayList<Question>)questionDAO.getAllQuestions();
}
```

If your goal is to return a list of item you can use:

```
@Path("all")
@GET
public Question[] getAllQuestions() {
    return questionDAO.getAllQuestions().toArray(new Question[]{});
}
```

**Edit**
Added original answer above

Comment: does not seem to make a difference:(

Comment: See edit, just out of interest, what version of JAX are you using?

Comment: I had not added the @XMLRootElement annotation on the domain class, now it works. It did work with you first example then:)

Comment: Are the questions returned for getAllQuestions() just strings or Objects ? If it is objects are they displayed as XML? Can you post a sample response?

Comment: They are objects and being displayed as JSON.

Answer (score 6):

The same problem in my case was solved by adding the POJOMappingFeature init param to the REST servlet, so it looks like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Now it even works with returning List on Weblogic 12c.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should set proper `@Produces` annotation.
And second, you can use [`GenericEntity`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/GenericEntity.html) to serialize a list.

```java
@GET
@Path("/questions")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response read() {

    final List<Question> list; // get some

    final GenericEntity<List<Question>> entity
        = new GenericEntity<List<Question>>(list) {};

    return Response.ok(entity).build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your webservice may look like this:

```
@GET
@Path("all")
@Produces({ "application/xml", "application/*+xml", "text/xml" })
public Response getAllQuestions(){
 List<Question> responseEntity = ...;
 return Response.ok().entity(responseEntity).build();
}
```

then you should create a Provider, MessageBodyWriter:

```
@Produces({ "application/xml", "application/*+xml", "text/xml" })
@Provider
public class XMLWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<Source>{

}
```